# setting onscreen keyboard type in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I was wondering whether the soft keyboard that pops up when we want to type anything in android can be configured. For example, in iOS, we can set the type of the keyboard to be numeric or alphanumeric or email etc. Is there anything similar in Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Use

```
 android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

As a XML tag for EditText's and other writtable widgets

Comment: @code_For_Life22 btw, ho do we specify a numeric keyboard ? `android:inputType="TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER"` doesnt work!!:(

Comment: It shouldnt be "TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER" it should be android:inputType = "number"